# How to prevent losing indentation when formatting in vscode?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, formatting, indentation

I have these lines in my code:

```php
class UpdateInternalCompanyNamesFromCompanyShortNames extends Command
{
    protected $signature =
        'update:internal-company-names-from-company-short-names';

    protected $description =
        'Copy company short names to internal company names (company_erp_name) from and to local database for all '
        . 'legal persons.';
```

After format, they turn into:

```php
class UpdateInternalCompanyNamesFromCompanyShortNames extends Command
{
    protected $signature =
    'update:internal-company-names-from-company-short-names';

    protected $description =
    'Copy company short names to internal company names (company_erp_name) from and to local database for all '
        . 'legal persons.';
```

Notice that the new line after the equals sign loses its indent. This alone prevents me from using the formatter, but when I see the second line after $description stays indented, it just makes me morose.

I've checked both UI and JSON settings for phpfmt and found nothing. Googling didn't help either.

Does anyone know how to deal with that, using [Intelephense](https://intelephense.com/)?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Prettier code formatter?

https://prettier.io/docs/en/index.html

You can add it as an Extension for VSCode. You can change the configurations as you like by editing the configuration file.